# Display message according to the priority wise

Tags: php

i have an array like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [msg] => vvv 
                       [social] => 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [msg] => hhh 
                       [social] => 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [msg] => rrr 
                       [social] => jws 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [msg] => hhhh. 
                       [social] => fff 
                       [priority] => 3 ) 
)
```

i need to display this msg priority wise. The condition is msg will be changed on each page load. I have used `shuffle()` but it's not proper.

Is it possible to change the sequence of the array ??

Comment: is this array going to be same on each page, and which message need to show first `priority=1` or `priority=4`

Comment: obviously priority 1

Comment: ?? sorry dont undestand

Comment: "Obviously"... Sure, obvious... – Sure it's possible to change the sequence of items in an array, it's called *sorting*.

Comment: on first page load it will be display 1 by using array short ... whats next  ?? only one msg can be displayed

Comment: @deceze on sccond load it will be p2 ??? so dont mark as duplicate without reading the question properly also .. its already sorted according to priority wise

Comment: So on first page load the first message, next page load second message etc... then on the sixth page load it starts from the beginning...?

Comment: should i have to count the page load ??? isnt thir any other way to shuffle according to the priotywise

Answer (score 1):

finally what i have done is :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
[0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
[0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
[0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
[0] => Array ( [msg] => xyx 
                       [social] =>xxx 
                       [priority] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [msg] => vvv 
                       [social] => 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [msg] => hhh 
                       [social] => 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [msg] => rrr 
                       [social] => jws 
                       [priority] => 2 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [msg] => hhhh. 
                       [social] => fff 
                       [priority] => 3 ) 
)
```

After that suffle() . .

Answer (score 0):

Store the messages in a/the session, display one on each load:

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['messages'])) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = $messages;

    // sort by priority if necessary:
    // usort($_SESSION['messages'], function ($a, $b) { return $a['priority'] - $b['priority']; });
}

$message = array_shift($_SESSION['messages']);
echo $message['msg'];
```

---

To *rotate* the array (feedback to comment):

```
$messages[] = array_shift($messages);
```

Comment: i have tried it ??? :(  .. its not the solution fr MVC and ajax base loading i have also tried to create the session on index page but when the ajes load its clared the session

Comment: Huh? Why is it not a solution "for MVC", and how does AJAX factor into this?

Comment: just give the answer yes or no ..  is their any method to shuffle the array sequentially ??? like this  0 1 2 3 4  ---> 1 2 3 4 0 ---> 2 3 4 0 1

Comment: That's not "shuffling sequentially", that's called *rotating*. I've added how to do that to the answer.

Comment: There's no big difference between rotating the array and doing what I'm suggesting, just that rotating uses more session storage (assuming you'd store that in the session).